# reading large files using apache common io

Tags: java, string, parsing, io

Hi I am using following code to get all the lines in a list of strings using the `FileUtils.readLines` functionality from Apache commons IO library. here is my code,

```
List<String> lines=FileUtils.readLines(new File(fileName));
```

But whenever i send a file say 45MB with 1 million lines it gives me an out of memory error. What should be the solution. I need to process each individual line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read one line after the other

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
 try {
   while (it.hasNext()) {
    String line = it.nextLine();
     // do something with line
   }
 } finally {
  it.close();
 }
```

Comment: Hi, it turns out eclipse is giving that error, if i run that program separately using java -jar it is ok. any idea about it?

Comment: Ok, interesting part. Check the "Run Configuration" especially the "Arguments" tab, section "VM arguments". You can try to increase the heap size there. E.g. -Xmx512m depending on the concrete OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are running an enviroment 32 bits instead of 64 bits an also not using the VM arguments as follows:

```html
-d64 -Xmx6G
```

```
 IOUtils.toString((InputStream) new FileInputStream("C://exocerebro//userrecord.sql"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This file is about 810 mb